# make class serializable

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I search how to made this class serializable for a service (SOAP)

```
<Serializable()> _
    Public Class Items

        Inherits StringEnumBase(Of Items)
        Public Sub New(ByVal StrValue As String)
            MyBase.New(StrValue)
        End Sub

        <Description("item 1")> Public Shared ReadOnly ITEM1 As New Items("ValueOfItem1")
        <Description("item 2")> Public Shared ReadOnly ITEM2 As New Items("ValueOfItem2")
        <Description("item 3")> Public Shared ReadOnly ITEM3 As New Items("ValueOfItem3")

    End Class
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's ok for the attribute, but it must have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: your right, I didnt know how because of inherits. but its simple. 
 Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Nothing)
        End Sub

Comment: but I still have problem. my object didn't know my public items on soap

Comment: I pass a string and cast on my service